# jqueryui draggable move image with handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

how can I have a draggable image using a handler? I've read that handlers should be inside the draggable, but I can't really have another element inside an image.

I've got here a fiddle for better presentation:

http://jsfiddle.net/index/bfpWv/10/

Question is how should I be able to drag inside the `#viewport` and still move the `#image`?

**Edit**

I think the question was a little vague:

Cause right now (on the fiddle) when you click on the `#image` first and drag, it drags the `#image`. But when you click on the `#viewport` first, it doesn't. That's what I want to happen, when you click on the `#viewport` first and drag, it would still drag the `#image`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems jquery draggable requires the handlers are put inside the draggable. You can write your own draggable with just few lines of code. See my demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bfpWv/22/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="http://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/hot-sexy-redheads-12.jpg" />
    <div id="viewport"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isDragging, 
        top = 0, left = 0,
        curX, curY;

    $("#image").mousedown(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#container").mousedown(function (e) {
        isDragging = true;

        curX = e.pageX;
        curY = e.pageY;

        left = Number($("#image").css("margin-left").
                      toString().replace("px", ""));
        top = Number($("#image").css("margin-top").
                     toString().replace("px", ""));
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        if (isDragging){
            // reset
            isDragging = false;
            top = 0;
            left = 0;
        }
    });

    $("#container").mousemove(function(e){
        if (!isDragging) {
            return;
        }

        left += e.pageX - curX;
        top += e.pageY - curY;

        // set the position
        $("#image").css("margin-left", left + "px").
            css("margin-top", top + "px");

        curX = e.pageX;
        curY = e.pageY;  
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup! It really seems that way. And I guess there's no option for that right now. Thanks for this approach, this will work but I'm using [jrac](https://github.com/trepmag/jrac) for other stuff as well like coords, I guess I could still get it by changing and catching the movements but I'll continue using jrac for now and just put the #viewport below and just make do with a few boxes. But thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfpWv/2/). Please read the documentation from here:
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

You had to use the containment option in your `.draggable` method and you also need to put your image inside the `#viewport` in order to have it initially inside the `#viewport`. You can also keep it outside the `#viewport` and once you drag it inside the `#viewport` it wont let you drag it again outside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I need. I needed to be able to position a certain part of the image in the #viewport. But I want it to be able to drag even in the #viewport box.

Comment: sorry i did'nt got that. Do you want to drag the image outside the viewport as well? I am really unable to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, the thing I want to achieve is the same as how the fiddle I posted works, 'cept I want the #viewport to also move the image. Hope that clears it.

Answer (score 0):

considering your description 
**how should I be able to drag inside the `#viewport` and still move the `#image`**
 -- did that using simple z-index css style. Hope it helps this time.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfpWv/9/#run)

Comment: Hi. Sorry if my question is a little vague. What I am trying to do is when I click first inside the `#viewport` and start dragging it should still move the `#image`.